# How can I make padding apply to wrapped text with CSS?

Tags: css

I have a minimal example here: https://codepen.io/cpcpcpcpcpx/pen/VwZWoyJ

Containing the following:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.header-text {
  background: #aabbcc;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <h1>
    <span class='header-text'>
           Long text that wraps
         </span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

The horizontal padding only applies to the very beginning and end of the text where it wraps, but I want it to apply on every line. I'm OK with the border-radius not being at the line-break points of every line, but I need the padding to apply.

If I put padding-top into the .header-text class that applies to both lines, so I'm unclear why the points where lines wrap ignore the horizontal padding options.

Is there a way to do this in CSS?

Comment: maybe you can find answer [here](https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you want can be achieve using [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) and it will even work with `border-radius`:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.header-text {
  background: #aabbcc;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <h1>
    <span class='header-text'>
           Long text that wraps
         </span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change .header-text display to either block or inline-block

Comment: Unfortunately that changes the way the background appears so that instead of having a background colour slightly higher than the line, it then becomes a much bigger rectangle emcompassing multiple lines, which isn't what I need to achieve.

Comment: I had my text in a `<span>` so the padding was only working on the first word; when I changed it to `display:block;` then the padding began to wrap the text like I expected it to. I understand that this has other effects, but with the html the way it was on my page, it worked while other answers did not.

Answer (score -1):

you could try in another way

```
.header-text {
  padding: 0;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May it will help u out. Increase the `width` of the `.wrapper` so the `padding` will apply.

**HTML PAGE**

```
            <div class='wrapper'>
              <h1>
                <span class='header-text'>
                  Long text that wraps
                </span>
              </h1>
            </div>
```

**CSS Page**

```
            .wrapper {
              width: 500px;
            }

            h1 {
              font-size: 32px;
              font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
              line-height: 50px;
            }

            .header-text {
              background: #aabbcc;
              padding-left: 20px;
              padding-right: 20px;
              border-radius: 6px;
              padding-top:12px;
              padding-bottom:12px
            }
```

Comment: Not possible in this instance, and in some cases we want the wrapper to contain multiple lines.